# Geometry Nodes: How Do I Set the Scale Difference between Two Instanced Curve Circles?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am instancing a circle using Instance to Points.  I have managed to get the two circles scaled differently using an Index node on the Scale input.  But no matter how I manipulate the value, the distance between the curves stays the same.

How do I set this up so that I can just scale the outside curve?  Ultimately I want to be able to set them pretty close together and then fill them using a Fill Curve modifier.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk1m2xaih80hx1z/Instance%20Curve%20Scale%20How.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **multiply add** node might be a good option.  If you change the multiplier value of the node, it will change the radius of the outside circle as long as it has a positive value.

It may be that you have to realize the instances in order to use the fill curve node.

[image]

Comment: That's it!  Thank you, I have not been acquainted with the *multiply add* node before today.  Really appreciate you helping me out here, cheers.

Comment: Here is another answer that might interest you if you need more than one circle:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280309/how-can-i-scale-an-object-in-an-array-with-a-constant-offset/280317#280317