# How can I scale an object in an array with a constant offset?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

im trying to get an easy set up to create a constant array offset, im fine with any tricks that could do the job ^^ I tried using geometry nodes by looking a bit everywhere and combining stuff but couldn t get something clean.
I d like to be able to do any sort of shapes and having a clean/constant array

[image: with object offset]

[image: geometry nodes result but not a super flexible setup]

---

i actually want to do both scale and translate like this[image]

Comment: Offset in Geometry Nodes:
https://youtu.be/TgiYxz11BxE?t=1356
But it's paid.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood your question, but isn't this even possible with the "normal" array modifier?

Comment: Please be so kind, and do not expand your question afterwards, if an answer already exists, and you steer the topic in a completely different direction. I think that @MarkusvonBroady's answer is correct and should be marked as "Accepted Answer". You can always open a new question. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If scale change is all you're after, then just scale based on an original object, rather than recursively (which is what array modifier does):

[image]

Doing other simple¹ transformations is also trivial:

[image]

¹ – instances can be scaled, rotated, and translated.

Comment: hey thanks for that!